# Unexpected token error using Passport LocalStrategy, knex, and postgres

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js, passport-local, postgresql-11

I am trying to use a passport-local strategy and a knex connection to postgresql for user authentication on a nodejs app. Below is the dependencies to the app file as well as the LocalStrategy instance:

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express'), 
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    session = require('express-session'),
    passport = require('passport')
    bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    db = require('./db');
    queries = require('./queries');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
options = {};

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(options, (username, password, done) =>{ 
    queries.findOne().then((user)) => {
            console.log(user)
            if (!user) return done(null, false);
            if (!autHelpers.comparePass(password, user.password)) {
                return done(null, false);
            } else {
                return done(null, user);
            }
        }
}

));
```

In the queries file, I have placed the findOne() function to find users

**queries.js**

```
const knex = require ('./db');

module.exports = {
    findOne() {
        return knex('users').where("username", username).first()
    }
}
```

However, running the app gives me the following error in the console:

> .getOne()
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
>
> at createScript (vm. js:80:10)
>
> ...

It seems that it doesn't accept the `queries.findOne()` statement for some reason.  I tried the `passport.use` without the statements inside the `=> {}` and it doesn't lead to an error in the app.

Should I be writing the `queries.findOne()` in a different manner? I also thought of wrapping this function inside `app.use()` but I feel that is not logical.

It seems I have done a typo somewhere, but everything I try leads to a dead-end and I can't seem to figure this simple one out.

Comment: Where is the .getOne function ? The queries.js file only has a findOne function. In the body of that function an undefined 'username' variable  can also cause troubles.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `findOne()` not `getOne()`, I corrected accordingly in the post.  Also for the username, how should I define it? You mean in one of the conditions, or instead do you mean as a parameter after `options` ?

Comment: Ah, you mean in the findOne() function.  I agree it can cause troubles, but I get the same `unexpected token` error when I replace the variable with a string of a username I already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error probably comes from the promise syntax :

```
queries.findOne().then((user)) => {
   ...
})
```

It must be rewritten as :

```
queries.findOne().then((user) => {
   ...
})
```

And with the complete block below :

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(options, (username, password, done) =>{ 
    queries.findOne().then((user) => {
        console.log(user)
        if (!user) return done(null, false);
        if (!autHelpers.comparePass(password, user.password)) {
            return done(null, false);
        } else {
            return done(null, user);
        }
    }) // There was also a missing end parenthesis here
}));
```

To prevent this kind of syntax issues in the future, you can use a linter such as [eslint](https://eslint.org/).

Comment: Thank you! You are a gentleman and a scholar...such a ridiculous mistake, probably because it's the weekend :P I will accept the answer as it fixed the problem, and upvote for the linter comment ;) -  I agree, I will start using them, will save a lot of time and headache.